# I've just increased the disk's size but the old size is still display, what could be the cause and how can I fix it?

Tags: linux, centos6, lvm

I need to increase the size of the root logical volume on one of my CentOS 6 virtual servers.

I've extended the virtual machine disk space from 16g to 30g.

Then I've connected to the machine and created a new partition using fdisk and I've changed the partition's system id to Linux LVM (8e) and saved the changes to the disk.

Then I've created a physical volume from the newly created partition, Next I've added the new physical volume to the only volume group on the machine.

Next, I've resized the root logical volume by the amount I had.

In order to update the system with the new LV size I've rebooted the machine.

Now the machine is back up but when I run `df -H` I still see the old size of the LV which I've just resized.

You can see here that the VG size is 29.5G instead of 16G which is still display in the output of `df -H`:

```
[root@wiki01 ~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VolGroup
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               29.50 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7553
  Alloc PE / Size       7529 / 29.41 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       24 / 96.00 MiB
  VG UUID               z7qRmK-up5e-m2EL-Miad-9vmG-TUH9-uFoE4d

[root@wiki01 ~]# df -H
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       16G   13G  2.3G  85% /
tmpfs                 981M     0  981M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             500M   35M  440M   8% /boot
company.local:/ifs/Peer39/home
                      1.1T   16G  1.1T   2% /home
company.local:/ifs/Peer39/common
                      1.1T   57G  1.1T   6% /nfs
```

What could be the reason for this miss-match and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I forgot to run the `resize2fs` command and that's why the LV size hasn't been updated.

Running the next command fixed it for me:

```
resize2fs /dev/VolGroup/lv_root
```

`df -H`:

```
[root@wiki01 ~]# df -H
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       27G   16G  9.8G  62% /
tmpfs                 981M     0  981M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             500M   35M  440M   8% /boot
company.local:/ifs/product/home
                      1.1T   16G  1.1T   2% /home
company.local:/ifs/product/common
                      1.1T   57G  1.1T   6% /nfs
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you resized the actual filesystem as well as the logical volume? It doesn't look like you have.

Comment: We've answered at the same time and you were correct about the resize2fs. thanks anyways.